# Есть ли PHP функция - аналог деркективы RewriteRule из .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

Интересует, есть ли функция, которая сможет перенаправить на другой сайт (раздел сайта), не меняя при этом url в браузере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`, затем выводи полученные данные на страницу.

Comment: Неплохой костыль. )) Но я, к сожалению, это делаю для магаза на битриксе, а не для визитки, поэтому мне важно сохранение авторизации, товара в корзине и т.д.

Comment: Для магазина настрой лучше .htaccess.  
Сервер будешь поменьше нагружать.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно редактировать это дело из админки, а парсить родной .htaccess, изменять его и обратно создавать, мне кажется, несколько небезобасно, поэтому и ищу обходной путь.

Comment: Закрой админку от редактирования htaccess для всех, кроме суперадминов.

Парсить htaccess не надо, стоит просто вывести его в textarea полностью.

Comment: @Get дело в том что мне надо было написать именно интуитивный интерфейс добавления редиректов, то есть форма : старая ссылка, новая ссылка.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (условие смены)
    рендерим одно
else
    рендерим другое
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под рендерим?

Comment: Рендеринг - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

В зависимости от условий подставляйте нужный интерфейс (Представление страницы).
Тут лучше использовать MVC, но можно закостылить кучей условий/ кейсов.

Answer (score 0):

Делай `iframe` блоки, если я правильно понял, это наилучший вариант для тебя.